# PDE in coordinates

Tags: partial-differential-equations

> Consider the equation $u_{xx}+2u_{xy}+u_{yy}=0.$ Write the equation in the coordinates $s=x, \ t =x-y$ and find the general solution of the equation.

So we have that $x=s$ and $y=s-t$ then assume that $u$ is a solution of the pde and thus have $v(s,t)=u(s,s-t)$. But a hint gives that $v_s=u_x+u_y$ and $v_{ss}=u_{xx}+u_{xy}+u_{yx}+u_{yy},$ how was that obtained?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any function $z(x,y)$, the chain rule gives
$$\frac{\partial z}{\partial s}=z_xx_s+z_yy_s=z_x+z_y\ .\tag{$*$}$$
Applying this to $z=u$ gives
$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial s}=u_x+u_y\ ,$$
and so
$$\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial s^2}
  =\frac{\partial u_x}{\partial s}+\frac{\partial u_y}{\partial s}\ .\tag{$*\!*$}$$
But now applying $(*)$ to $u_x$ and $u_y$ gives
$$\frac{\partial u_x}{\partial s}=u_{xx}+u_{xy}\ ,\quad
  \frac{\partial u_y}{\partial s}=u_{yx}+u_{yy}\ ;$$
substituting back into $(**)$ gives
$$u_{ss}=u_{xx}+2u_{xy}+u_{yy}\ ,$$
assuming that $u_{yx}=u_{xy}$.

---

Writing this in terms of a different function $v$ is probably, strictly speaking, correct.  But IMHO it is really just confusing, and I prefer to think of it as the same quantity, just written in terms of different variables.  By way of comparison, think of writing the circumference of a circle as
$$C=2\pi r=u(r)\ ,\quad C=\pi d=v(d)\ .$$
These are two different functions, but surely the easy way to think of it is that it is the same quantity written in terms of different variables.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

Use the chain rule:
$$v_s = v_x x_s + v_y y_s = u_x + u_y$$

Comment: How did you derive $v_s$?

Comment: @Robben - I didn't need to derive it, it's just the chain rule: http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcIII/ChainRule.aspx